# Not cretaing proc/bus/ entry in Linux-3.10.14 for usb modem

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, libusb

My Linux kernel version is 3.10.14 and I am using libusb-1.0.21 . I cross compiled it for mipsel-linux  on my router for usb modem. when I try to run usb_modeswitch I got the following error :
Error: Failed to initialize libusb. LIBUSB_ERROR_OTHER (-99)
I found there is no entry /proc/bus for the attached usb modem.
Can anybody tell me what to do resolve this issue.

I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Can you please share the output of 'lspci | grep USB'

Comment: # lspci
00:00.0 Class 0604: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
00:01.0 Class 0604: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
01:00.0 Class 0280: Device 14c3:7662
02:00.0 Class 0280: Device 14c3:7662

Comment: # lspci | grep USB is giving nothing but 
lspci is giving the following output
00:00.0 Class 0604: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
00:01.0 Class 0604: Device 0e8d:0801 (rev 01)
01:00.0 Class 0280: Device 14c3:7662
02:00.0 Class 0280: Device 14c3:7662

Also in the lastest kernel-3.10.14 /proc/bus/usb is not creating for usb dongle ,due to which libusb can't able to read and the usb_modeswitch is not working.